# Why MPI doesn't work in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, mpi

I downloaded and installed `mpich2-1.0.8p1-win-x86-64.msi` from the console with the administrator rights. I created empty win32 console project, I created file code.cpp and I pasted this example code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int ProcNum, ProcRank, RecvRank;
    MPI_Status Status;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &ProcNum);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &ProcRank);
    if (ProcRank == 0)
    { 
            printf("\n Hello from process %3d", ProcRank);
        for (int i = 1; i < ProcNum; i++)
        {
            MPI_Recv(&RecvRank, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE,
                MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Status);
            printf("\n Hello from process %3d", RecvRank);
        }
    }
    else
        MPI_Send(&ProcRank, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Later I went to project properties to VC++ Directories and added include directories and library directories. In Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies I wrote mpi.lib and in C/C++/Language I allowed Open MP Support. When I compiled my project I have got strange errors. Can you help me? I can't understand what I made wrong, because I did it with tutorials.

[image: errors]

Comment: OpenMP support isn't necessary for MPI. From your error list (specifically, the first warning), it looks like you provided the path to the 64-bit MPI library, while you are compiling for a 32-bit architecture. Either provide it the 32-bit library, or compile for a 64-bit architecture.

Comment: 'I wrote mpi.lib and in C/C++/Language'.  What programming language is called 'Language'?

Comment: @R_Kapp thanks, it helped me. Write this in answer and I will choose this for a solution.

Comment: @Deanie it is the name of directory in properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first (and only) warning states that you are linking a 64-bit library with a 32-bit build. You need to either provide a 32-bit library or build for a 64-bit architecture to get rid of the linker errors.